# SQL - replace returned data with other data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2005

I am retrieving data using the SQL syntax below:

```
SELECT TOP 5 EventId, EventTime, DeviceName, Comment, Tenant, TenantName, Individual, 
                InetDb.dbo.Individuals.FirstName, InetDb.dbo.Individuals.LastName, InetDb.dbo.IndivImages.UserImage
                FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event
                LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants
                    ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
                LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.Individuals
                    ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Individual = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.IndivId 
                    AND taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx
                LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.IndivImages
                    ON InetDb.dbo.Individuals.IndivId = InetDb.dbo.IndivImages.IndivNdx
                    AND InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx = InetDb.dbo.IndivImages.TenantNdx
                WHERE (taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime  > DATEADD(hh, -3, GETDATE())AND taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime < GETDATE())
                    AND (taclogdata.dbo.Event.Comment='Reader entry' OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.Comment='Reader exit')
                    AND (taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName = 'L9 1/4/1' 
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/1/1-2 MainD'
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/1/3-4 MainD'
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/6/1-2 Stair'
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/2/1-2 FDT1')
                ORDER BY taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime DESC
```

This code works fine, however I'm trying to simplify the results.
I'm trying to simplify what the query returns, by replacing the DeviceName value from e.g. **L1 2/1/3-4 MainD** to **Main Door** when the results are shown (not replace the actual data in the database)

How may I achieve this please ?
Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: It depends if you just want one replacement or a bunch of different. I've added you my both suggestions.

Comment: You should also change the series of `OR`s to a single `IN` statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1):

try this use replace function

```
SELECT TOP 5 EventId, EventTime, replace(DeviceName,'L1 2/1/3-4 MainD','L1 2/1/3-4 Main Door') as DeviceName, Comment, Tenant, TenantName, Individual, 
                InetDb.dbo.Individuals.FirstName, InetDb.dbo.Individuals.LastName, InetDb.dbo.IndivImages.UserImage
                FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event
                LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants
                    ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
                LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.Individuals
                    ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Individual = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.IndivId 
                    AND taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx
                LEFT JOIN InetDb.dbo.IndivImages
                    ON InetDb.dbo.Individuals.IndivId = InetDb.dbo.IndivImages.IndivNdx
                    AND InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx = InetDb.dbo.IndivImages.TenantNdx
                WHERE (taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime  > DATEADD(hh, -3, GETDATE())AND taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime < GETDATE())
                    AND (taclogdata.dbo.Event.Comment='Reader entry' OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.Comment='Reader exit')
                    AND (taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName = 'L9 1/4/1' 
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/1/1-2 MainD'
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/1/3-4 MainD'
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/6/1-2 Stair'
                        OR taclogdata.dbo.Event.DeviceName='L1 2/2/1-2 FDT1')
                ORDER BY taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mukesh.  
Can you explain how I can how to apply this for more than 1, e.g. replace 'L1 2/1/3-4 MainD' with 'Main Door. Replace L1 2/1/3-4 MainD with Secondary Main door. Replace 'L1 2/6/1-2 Stair' with Stair Door, etc.

Comment: @joebegborg07 try this : replace(replace(DeviceName,'L1 2/6/1-2 Stair','L1 2/6/1-2 Stair Door'),'L1 2/1/3-4 MainD','L1 2/1/3-4 Main Door')

Answer (score 1):

Here my suggestions:

If you can replace the data in your `SELECT` for example:

```
SELECT REPLACE(DeviceName,N'2/1/3-4 MainD',N'Main Door')
```

If you have many replacements, I would suggest to create a temporary table, join it and take the replacement from the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

The specific answer to your question is to use `REPLACE()` or a `CASE` statement. However, you should also change the `WHERE` clause to use `IN` and use table aliases so the code is easier to write and to read:

```
FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event e LEFT JOIN
     InetDb.dbo.Tenants t
     ON e.Tenant = t.TenantId LEFT JOIN
     InetDb.dbo.Individuals i
     ON e.Individual = i.IndivId AND e.Tenant = i.TenantNdx LEFT JOIN
     InetDb.dbo.IndivImages ii
     ON i.IndivId = ii.IndivNdx AND Ii.TenantNdx = ii.TenantNdx 
WHERE (e.EventTime  > DATEADD(hour, -3, GETDATE()) AND 
       e.EventTime < GETDATE()
      ) AND
      e.Comment IN ('Reader entry', 'Reader exit') AND
      e.DeviceName IN ('L9 1/4/1', 'L1 2/1/1-2 MainD', 'L1 2/1/3-4 MainD',
                       'L1 2/6/1-2 Stair', 'L1 2/2/1-2 FDT1'
                      )
```